# Cordova / Phonegap 2.8 external links - no return

Tags: hyperlink, cordova

Whilst my external links, like this

a href="http://www.texthere target="_blank"  data-role="button">text here<

work, they open in a page that I can't navigate back from. The external URL opens in a window, and even if I close the app and re-open I go back to that external page rather than the app page that I clicked on the link from.

Grateful for any help!

Thanks.

Comment: If you want to use the back button, you probably need to not use `target=_blank`, which opens a new page with no history.

Comment: Thanks for the response, however I have just tried that and the issue remains.

Answer (score 0):

To use InAppBrowser, you must keep a reference to it so that you can close the browser to go back to your browser: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html

Otherwise, attach to the click event and use:  navigator.app.loadUrl(yourUrl, { openExternal: true });

I think there's also a "_system" target but I don't know if it works on the anchor tag though.
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#window.open

Comment: OK, thanks - my config.xml now contains     <plugins>
<plugin name="InAppBrowser" value="CDVInAppBrowser" />  
</plugins>, but I'm not sure what else to do - any help appreciated thanks.

Comment: I don't know how to add navigator.app.loadUrl(yourUrl, { openExternal: true }); - can you give me any tips? Thanks

Comment: Listen to the click event of your anchor tag and execute loadUrl in a method.  <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="your method for loadUrl">...</a>  Also use FastClick.js to polyfill and improve your click response time.